# Stop windows defender/Antivirus from detecting myapp

Tags: windows, vb.net, security

I create a program, that purpose is to update the main program. This updater is called each time user run the main program. But updater program keep detected as virus by windows defender/ other anvtivirus.
Updater life cycle are

1. check to server is there is an update or not
2. if there is an update, it will download it
3. replace/copy the file
4. close it self

Is there any way to stop it being detected as virus WIHTOUT put it in exception list

Comment: AFAIK Microsoft Defender assumes every program to be evil if it didn't see it before (anywhere on the internet). If the program was marked as _okay_ by enough users, the program won't be considered dangerous in the future and the warning will be gone (for all following users). To skip this _graylisting phase_ you have to purchase an EV certificate (expensive) and sign your application with it. In that case the defender won't show the initial warning anymore, cause even if the program is dangerous, it can be traced back to the producer.

Comment: If one was able to accomplish this, what would prevent someone from creating a legitimate program only to _update_ the program later with a malicious version (ie: virus, trojan, etc...)?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is code-sign your executable. Unsigned executables will usually be prevented from running.

If you are in an enterprise environment, your IT admins can use the company certification authority (CA) to issue a code-signing certificate and then whitelist apps developed using it inside your domain. This won't help installing your app on non-company PCs though.

Otherwise you'll need to pay for a code-signing certificate from one of the big CAs.

Answer (score 0):

submit your program as a false positive on https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a program that, by manipulating tokens, stops the defender and in the latest version 1.03 adds itself to exceptions with TI+WinDefend rights (right into the registry) automatically. So, yes it is possible.
You can use the engine's source code:
https://youtu.be/6WqiULYbrh8
https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/stopping-and-starting-the-windows-defender-service-on-demand.86948/
Regarding "visibility" by AV. It is also possible to do it using PE encryption and anti-debug, but it would require constant updates and strong obfuscation not only of the code, but also of the import/API fuzzing